# Adding svelte components if not production

Tags: svelte, rollupjs, sapper

So I am currently trying to setup a sort of "blackbox" mode for my app.

And as such I have a lot of random generated data that I can use for testing. But it is kind of tricky to get the credentials for all my users, so I was thinking that I could just create a component that acts as a user browser and I can just pick a user and get authenticated as it.

But the question is: can I create such a component and have it visible on all pages assuming that it is not compiled for production?

Might be something that has to be done in rollup?

also if relevant, I am running svelte + sapper

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally render an `if` block using `process.env.NODE_ENV`, like:

```
{#if process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'}
   <MyDevOnlyComponenet />
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your rollup config (assuming you are using svelte plugin) -

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
export default {
    input: "inputFileName.js",
    output: {
        file: fileNamePath
    },
    plugins: [
        !isProduction && svelte()
    ]
};
```